# the grammatical point of this sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs

Would someone describe how this sentence is created? I am kind of confused about `being` part and what the original sentence before reducing had been:

> There was a sharp rise in the earning of the shop to 10K, this number being the peak level of income during the whole period.

Comment: It's a kind of ["run-on sentence"](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/runonsentences) that features a "literary" use of the continuous participle ***being*** rather than the normal tensed verb form of *This number **is** the peak level of income during the whole period.* Another example: *I asked John if I could go, **him being** the man in charge* - which is equivalent to *I asked John if I could go, **because he was** the man in charge* (there's often an implied "because" with this construction).

Comment: I couldn't tell you how it was created, except that it was probably written by a non-native speaker, since it has mistakes natives don't make. It appears to be trying to describe an earnings graph.